# How to push existing repo using Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have been given access of Git Lab account with project repo url.

How do I push my project on GitLab.

is it similar to pushing as Git ?

Comment: yes it is. Git is the same. Gitlab etc are servers for hosting repos. So the same command will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing things. `Git` and `GitLab` are entirely incomparable :/.

`GitLab` is `Git` on a server.

`Git` is a source code management system for software development. It is a distributed revision control system. Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29

`GitLab` is one out of many solutions out there that allows you to manage `git` repositories on a centralized server. Other solutions include `GitHub`, `Gitorious`. Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab